# How to handle very large file downloads using React js

Tags: reactjs, large-files

We are trying to download large files say 1GB or 2 GB but after certain time though the backend still goes on the UI gives error as Failed to fetch for large files.

So how can we handle large file downloads using React js

Please help!

Code as below:

```
getFile = async (endpoint: string, id: string, params?: any) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    this.createUrl(endpoint + "/" + id, params),
    this.getRequest("get", {
      Accept: "application/octet-stream",
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    }),
  );
  if (response.status === 200) {
    return await response.blob();
  } else {
    throw Error(errorObj.error);
  }
};

downloadFile = (filepath: any) => {
  this.props.api.getFile(resource, filepath, {}).then((res: any) =>
    this.setState(() => {
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res]));
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute("download", path.basename(filepath));
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      link.parentNode!.removeChild(link);
      toaster.success("Successfully downloaded ");
    }),
  );
};
```

Comment: "Failed to fetch"? That sounds like you're attempting to load the file into memory using `fetch()`, not download it straight to disk. Please show us some code.

Comment: downloadFile = (filepath: any) => {
      this.props.api.getFile(
            resource, filepath,{})
            .then((res: any) => this.setState(() => {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res]));
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute("download", path.basename(filepath));
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                link.parentNode!.removeChild(link);
                toaster.success("Successfully downloaded " );
}))

Comment: public getFile = async (endpoint: string, id: string, params?: any) => {
        const response = await fetch(
            this.createUrl(endpoint + "/" + id, params),
            this.getRequest("get", {"Accept": "application/octet-stream", "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"})
        );
        if (response.status === 200) {
            return await response.blob();
        } else {
            throw Error(errorObj.error);
        }
    };

Comment: Please add the code in your question, not in comments. It's impossible to read there.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into it... I have added it in the question now

Answer (score 2):

Using `fetch` will buffer the response into memory, and you can't quite expect to buffer 1 to 2 gigabytes in memory. (You *could* do something clever with IndexedDB like e.g. Mega does, but it's likely not worth it.)

Instead of `fetch`ing the data from an URL (let's call it URL A) and creating an Object URL from the content blob to put in a download link you click, simply put URL A in the download link.

If the endpoint at URL A requires some authentication or similar, you will need to change that to something that can be encoded into query parameters; maybe a token with a signature akin to what AWS S3 does with presigned URLs.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs can you please help me with an example for it.

Comment: Please help with this query.....I tried getting the example but they are not working